# How can a PHP callback be passed as non-string and therefore be made refactorable?

Tags: php

Introduced in PHP 5.5, it is possible to use the `MyClass::class` [syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) to reference a class instead of passing it as `'MyClass'`, which is not easily refactorable as it's just a string.

I would very much like to do the same thing with the function name, when passing a callback/callable to `call_user_func()` or `usort()`.

In the example

```
usort($files, [FileFunctions::class, 'dircmp']);
```

only `FileFunctions` can easily be refactored.

How can I reference the `dircmp` function in a similar way?

Using

```
usort($a, FileFunctions::dircmp);
```

leads to a `Undefined class constant 'dircmp'` fatal error, as the parameter after the double colons is interpreted as a constant (of course).

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd say only an anonymous function wrapper will do. Which is obviously quite a pain in the neck.

Comment: a question.. why you have to write FileFunctions::class instead 'FileFunctions' .. what do you win?

Comment: @Svetlio IDE can unambiguously tell that's it's a reference to a class instead of just a random string, and *help with refactoring*.

Comment: @deceze True. It's a nice idea, but very cumbersome to do. Wondering what the best practice is with this. I really don't like to pass function names as strings.

Comment: Me neither, but that's PHP for ya. Functions aren't first-class entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

class FileFunctions {
    static function dircmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a == $b) return 0;
        return ($a > $b) ? 1:-1;
    }
}

$files = [2,6,1,6,9,2,6,1,7,4];

usort($files, function($a, $b) {return FileFunctions::dircmp($a, $b);});
var_dump($files);
```

PHPStorm10 correctly refactored `dircmp`

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting dicussions regarding this in this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/47jxd0/rfc_callable_constructors/d0eip6k

> > the current syntax for calling dynamically using methods as a callback is rather awful
>
> That seems a difficult problem to solve. People who've looked at it
>   have said that it can't be solved without either merging the symbol
>   tables (which isn't ever likely to happen, as it breaks too much
>   code), or alternatively with a new syntax. One thing that would be
>   possible without clashing with any existing syntax is to use $() to be
>   a language construct of 'give me a callable/closure' of this thing:
>
> ```
> $(functionName);  // Usable at compile time.
> $(SomeClass::staticMethodNameAsString); //Usable at compile time
> $($object->methodName); //Usable at runtime
> ```
>
> Without merging the symbol tables, that's almost certainly the
>   cleanest, in the sense of the smallest number of characters, to
>   implement it. I can't see any problems with that (other than it's new
>   syntax which everyone gets scared by), but it's beyond my skills to
>   implement.

and

> Props for taking the feedback well. There's definitely need for the
>   problem to be solved in a cleaner way than our current options.
>
> I completely agree that solving the greater callback syntax is very
>   tricky. Even some sort of syntactic sugar that converts a method call
>   into the current array-as-callable could help a lot. The main issue I
>   have with explicitly using strings is that it makes finding call sites
>   of methods drastically harder, both with static analysis and even
>   basic tools like grep. You can't simply `grep -ri -- '->someMethodCall(' *` when it's being invoked with `[$obj, 'someMethodCall']`, and looking for the method name without arrows or
>   parens tends to leave a lot of false positives.